# Excel - copying links without forumla

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, hyperlink

I have a column of hyperlinks in an excel file.

I've used formula: "=HYPERLINK(A2,A2)" and it gives me a hyperlink to a file on drive.

In column A there are text versions of alll of the links - source filepaths, I want that column to now have the live links. So I try to copy the hyperlink column over - this does not work.

In the formula bar it shows as the formula, not the link and I want to paste these links over the A2 so the A column has the link.

Any advice without using macros would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to do this using:

Copy - Paste Special > Paste values.

A normal paste is designed to preserve the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this all contained in the `HYPERLINK` function? It takes 2 parameters: the actual link and a 'friendly name' for the link.

[image: hyperlink]

If that's not what you're looking for, could you show what your data looks like and what you want it to look like?